# Array.filter() won't filter the last item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, google-maps

I'm using React, Javascript and Google Maps Autocomplete to allow users to add regions. These regions are then added to an array, mapped through on the screen and then a user can click on a region in order to delete the item from the array and therefore the screen.

`onDelete` filters whatever the user clicks and leaves whatever is left. It works for every element in the array except the last element. Then when i click, it deletes temporarily and then adds it again. You can see on the below screenshot.

Here are my attempts to delete the code below.
[image]

[image]

First image shows the array. The second image shows how i can delete certain elements before the last one and my attempts to delete the last element, "Cape Town, Western Cape".

How i add to the array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Used to ensure that there are no duplicates
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (region) {
      if (!regions.includes(region)) {
        setRegions((prevValue) => {
          return [...prevValue, region];
        });
      }
    }
    handleAddData("regions", regions);

    return () => {
      isSubscribed = false;
    };

}, [region, regions, handleAddData]);
```

How i delete from the array:

```
const onDelete = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    console.log("Click onDelete: ", value);

    setRegions(regions.filter((item) => item !== value));
  };
```

How its displayed to the user:

```
<ul>
          {regions.map((region) => (
            <li
              key={region}
              title="remove"
              onClick={onDelete}
              value={region}
            >
              {region}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        {regions && <p>Click to remove</p>}
```

I would create a reproducible version but its tricky since i'm using Google Maps.

Comment: What is in the dependency array for your `useEffect`? In general sideeffects of handlers (such as adding to an array) should be managed in the handler itself and not in a `useEffect`. see [React Docs: You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Comment: I have 2 useEffects. The one in the question and the other useEffect i have is just to console.log the regions with regions as a dependency. I made that one for this problem specifically.

Comment: but what is `region` in the effect you've shown, and what is in the dependency array?

Comment: Oh, okay. I just added the dependencies. I wasn't aware that i had missed that. ```region``` is the one selection that is chosen by the user in AutoComplete. This is added to ```regions```.

Comment: Since you have `regions` in the dependency array every time you filter your `regions` array you will trigger that effect. Are you certain that `region` is empty at that point? Otherwise it will add whatever is currently in `region` to the end of the array everytime you filter.

Comment: You are right. The reason why it only affects the last element is because when deleting the last element added, the only thing that can be added is the latest element so after deletion the useEffect runs and adds region again.

Comment: Glad it helped. As I mentioned earlier, try to handle side effects in the specific handlers (ie. `onAdd()` `onDelete()`) and only use effects for component wide logic such as initial data fetching.